# Menu key in terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

In many OS you have the option to press the Menu key when you are inside the terminal. This displays a menu, as if you had right clicked, showing options like copy, paste, cut ...

Is there a way I can do this in Loki?

[image: Menu Key]

Comment: I don't think so. This might be better filed as a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into this utility: http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html

It's in the repos, and there is also a configuration gui for it

```
apt-cache search xbindkeys
```

will find it.

Answer (score 0):

The Menu key is, by default, used as the compose key. So MENU+' e gives é in terminal or any other application. You can turn this off in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Options. But there does not seem to be an option then to bring up an actual menu with the button.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is added to pantheon-terminal version 5.3.6+. 
Please update your system `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.